# Formatar apenas ultimos caracteres de valores de uma coluna no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se tem como formatar apenas os ultimos caracteres de valores de um coluna do meu banco de dados

por exemplo
image.jpeg para image.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi uma resposta orientando usar `locate()` e tenho certeza `SUBSTRING_INDEX` é mais apropriado.

1. `locate()` procura a primeira ocorrência de um identificador de extensão, o `ponto`. mas se o arquivo tiver outro ponto a mais no nome, tu tá lascado.
2. `SUBSTRING_INDEX` entretanto, subdivide uma string em outras strings. e você pode escolher iniciar pela esquerda ou direita. Como teu problema é identificar extensão de arquivos, é melhor pegar substrings a partir da última ocorrência de um `ponto` no texto.

Nesse exemplo, o comando abaixo já identifica possíveis situações:

```sql
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Meu arquivo.documento.jpg', '.',-1);
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Meu.arquivo.jpeg', '.',-1);
```

O resultado desses comandos vão ser a própria extensão do arquivo.
1. jpg
2. jpeg

Aí você vai montar uma query para atualizar todas as extensões para jpg.

```sql
    UPDATE tabela SET 
       coluna = REPLACE(coluna, SUBSTRING_INDEX(coluna,'.',-1), 'jpg');
```

Caso queira ser mais criterioso, daí você pode trabalhar somente os registros que estão errados:

```sql
    UPDATE tabela SET 
       coluna = REPLACE(coluna, SUBSTRING_INDEX(coluna,'.',-1), 'jpg')
    WHERE 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(coluna, '.',-1) = 'jpeg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `UPDATE` e utilizar o comando `locate()` no WHERE.
O comando `locate()` serve para você encontrar uma substring dentro de uma string. Você poderia então buscar a substring ".j" e fazer um update where substring ".j" > 0 e setando o texto para o novo valor.

A estrutura do comando locate é:

```
LOCATE(substr,str,pos)
```

- substr = o texto que você quer encontrar na string (no caso o jpeg)
  str = a string onde vocÊ quer encontrar o texto (o texto da coluna
  que você quer alterar) pos = posição para buscar. Você pode
  especificar a posição para ele começar a buscar ***OPCIONAL***
- Este comando retorna um valor numérico.

Então, por exemplo, seria um UPDATE mais ou menos assim:

```
UPDATE tabela SET coluna = image.jpg WHERE LOCATE('.jpeg', coluna) > 0
```

Se cada imagem tiver um nome diferente você ainda pode usar `CHAR_LENGTH()` e `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` para pegar apenas parte do nome e colocar no novo nome.